# How to check string value in stored proc

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am a java developer. I need to write a stored proc. In my stored proc based on conduction I need to check some chars

```
R_ROW IS RECORD(SELECT ACCNT_NBR, ....... QUEUE, INBOX_USER_TEAM,.. WHERE .....
LOOP
QUEUE_VAR:=R_ROW.QUEUE;
INBOX_TEAM_VAR:=R_ROW.INBOX_USER_TEAM;

IF(QUEUE_VAR='INBOX')THEN
```

-- I need to check INBOX_TEAM_VAR value contains '%UND%'

-- Its like query. `SELECT.... FROM... WHERE INBOX_TEAM_VAR LIKE '%UND%'`

-- please help me how to implement this logic, because performers issue I should not query that table again.

```
ELSIF(QUEUE_VAR='COMPLETE') THEN
    -- do logic
ELSIF(QUEUE_VAR='AUDIT') THEN
    -- do logic
.....
....
....
END IF;
```

Thanks is advance, Appropriated for your help and time on this

CVSR Sarma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIKE` works in PL/SQL pretty same as in in SQL:

```
IF INBOX_TEAM_VAR LIKE '%UND%' THEN ...
```

ADDITION: Or you can use `INSTR` function instead:

```
IF INSTR(INBOX_TEAM_VAR, 'UND') > 0 THEN ...
```